# Get Firebase database from another firebase app

Tags: ios, firebase-realtime-database, swift5

How to access firebase database from another firebase app in swift5?
We have two apps in one account one is driver app and rider app.
I am storing data in driver real time database and want to access that database in rider app.
Let me know if anyone have this solution.

Answer (score 0):

To access the same database from two iOS application, you simply create two apps in the Firebase console of that project. This will give you a `GoogleService-Info.plist` file with information about both apps, and each app will pick its configuration from there based on the iOS bundle ID.

Also see step 2 of [register your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#register-app) in the Firebase setup instructions for iOS developers.

After this both apps can access the same database, as well as all other services.

Comment: I already register both apps in one account. but when trying to get database of one app in the second app. App crashing showing error "INVALID URL". I am trying to get data from the database url.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to use multiple firebase database in a single iOS app

```
func initDatabase() {

FIRDatabase().database() // gets you the default database
    let options = FIROptions(googleAppID:  bundleID: , GCMSenderID: , APIKey: , clientID: , trackingID: , androidClientID: , databaseURL: "https://othernamespace.firebaseio.com", storageBucket: , deepLinkURLScheme: ) // fill in all the other fields 
    FIRApp.configureWithName("anotherClient", options: options)
    let app = FIRApp(named: "anotherClient")
    FIRDatabase.database(app: app!) // gets you the named other database
 }
```

Or you can initialize from another named plist rather than a huge constructor:

```
let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Second-GoogleService-Info", ofType:"plist")
let options = FIROptions(contentsOfFile:filePath)
```

Comment: So you mean i need to add 2 Google-info.plist in one app. Right?